# How can I avoid running out of memory with a growing TDictionary?

Tags: delphi, memory-management, collections, delphi-xe

`TDictionary<TKey,TValue>` uses an internal array that is doubled if it is full:

```
newCap := Length(FItems) * 2;
if newCap = 0 then
  newCap := 4;
Rehash(newCap);
```

This performs well with medium number of items, but if one gets to the upper limit it is very unfortunate, because it might throw an `EOutOfMemory` exception even if there  is almost half of the memory still available.

Is there any way to influence this behaviour? How do other collection classes deal with this scenario?

Comment: I think the basic assumption is that you don't consume half of your entire available resources in a single `TDictionary` instance. It's not designed for such usage.

Comment: So that would be a "no, it is not possible"?

Comment: Once you get to having consumed half of the memory, how do you do any reallocation. Suppose you want to add another 10%. You've got to allocate a new block, 10% bigger than the existing. Then copy from old to new. Then deallocate old. That's not going to work out. It sounds odd to me that a single container could consume more than half of your resources.

Comment: Good point about the reallocations. That explains why it threw earlier than I expected. I'm still trying differenct scenarios for keeping a very large number of objects in memory.

Comment: David: while true, the behaviour still halves the maximal workable size. Whatever percentage of memory you think is allowable for the TDictionary

Comment: @Marco The true limit here will be **contiguous** virtual address space.

Comment: The other point is that for performance reasons you need to have some empty parts of the underlying array. If you don't then your hash goes from O(1) retrieval to O(n) retrieval.

Comment: I'd be curious, how many items are you actually inserting into the dictionary itself? I know I've pushed TDictionary myself in the past, and it goes *very* far before braking. It might be that all the objects you're trying to index are using a lot of space, and in that case TDictionary is just a symptom. And in that case replacing TDictionary with something else is not going to help.

Comment: @Smasher What is `TKey` and what is `TValue`?

Comment: David: of course, but the workable size of that is also halved, for exactly the same reasons. Usually it is wiser to stop doubling container types, when some threshold (say a few tens of thousands items) is reached, and then increase by 10 or 20%. So I sympathise with Smasher. (if the whole dictionary is really allocated statically and he doesn't use reference types as key or value)

Comment: @Marco The difference here is that the hashed dictionary needs over capacity to perform well

Comment: Huh? A certain key to bucket ratio. But allocation? The number of buckets is typically lower than the allocations.

Comment: @Marco It doesn't use buckets. Look at the source.

Comment: @David: if it was unique, I would not have made it generic :) In most cases `TKey` will be a handle and `TValue` will be a record.

Comment: @Smasher I mean in the real world case where you are running out of memory. How big is the record? You may well get much better performance if you store pointers to the records, if they are big enough.

Comment: Have you considered moving the data out of memory and into a file based database? This is with the assumption that they have more disk space than RAM.

Comment: +1 Marcus, when you are stressing the RAM limits (for whatever reasons), it's time to look at professional database solutions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to understand how a Dictionary works. A dictionary contains a list of "hash buckets" where the items you insert are placed. That's a finite number, so once you fill it up you need to allocate more buckets, there's no way around it. Since the assignment of objects-to-buckets is based on the result of a hash function, you can't simply add buckets to the end of the array and put stuff in there, you need to re-allocate the whole list of blocks, re-hash everything and put it in the (new) corresponding buckets.

Given this behavior, the only way to make the dictionary *not* re-allocate once full is to make sure it never gets full. If you know the number of items you'll insert in the dictionary pass it as a parameter to the constructor and you'll be done, no more dictionary reallocations.

If you can't do that (you don't know the number of items you'll have in the dictionary) you'll need to reconsider what made you select the `TDictionary` in the first place and select a data structure that offers better compromise for your particular algorithm. For example you could use binary search trees, as they do the balancing by rotating information in existing nodes, no need for re-allocations *ever*.

Comment: +1 Thanks! What I thought of was some way to change the growth factor, so that I can calculate it in a way that lets me use the available memory. I'll look into binary search tree!

Comment: Changing the growth factor will not buy you much, if you're already getting to the point where you can no-longer re-allocate. You'll just get there slower, because you'll do more re-allocations along the way. And thanks to address space fragmentation you might get there slower AND with fewer items added.